# FHIR Adding Custom .create

Tags: hl7-fhir, epic

On fhir.epic.com I see a lot of different information you can add to a "patient chart". For example like allergy intolerances and conditions. Through the Create route you can add such info onto the patient's chart. However, is there a way where developers can add a custom create route. So, for example, I know a patients daily protein intake, but because the API doesn't have a protein.create I can't add it to the patient chart. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The whole point of the interface is to use standard resources.  Epic must map the data to their existing data.  If implementers passed in custom data structures, there'd be no way for Epic to map that to their standard data structures.

The specific element you mentioned would typically be captured using Observation.